# Is it really possible to classify pixels as foreground or background using statistical estimation/regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, image-processing

I'm studying Statistical Estimation and Detection, so it's important for me to understand this.

I've been going through [this paper](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXIX/congress/part5/600_XXIX-part5.pdf) which claims to relate an image pixel intensity `y` to the row and column positions of the pixel, and by analyzing the variances and having a null hypothesis with no noise and an alternate hypothesis with noise, the algorithm decides whether the pixel belongs to the foreground or background.

Defining the problem like this would be `y = x1*i + x2*j + e` where:
`y` is the pixel intensity estimated.
`x1` and `x2` are the coefficients to estimate.
`i` and `j` are pixel positions.
`e` is the zero mean error.
This would be the equation of a plane.

What I don't understand is that for example in an image [like this](http://www.californiaherps.com/snakes/images/cmpyrrhusimp2611.jpg), how can fitting a plane (with least squares approach) to a patch of pixel intensities tell us if the pixel in the middle of the patch belongs to the foreground or background? I've actually written a program for this and for a  square patch of pixels of 77x77 size processed for a single row of pixels in the middle of an image similar to the one I linked to, using least squares, it appears like the `e` term is handling most of the fitting (shown in black and green below). While the x1 and x2 terms are shown in red and blue pixels. Black pixels are what the ground truth image says are background, and green are what the ground truth says are foreground (snake).
[image]

Even when I plotted the x1 and x2 terms only (graph below), it does not seem to provide any indication of where the foreground begins or ends. The black and red pixels are just to tell us whether a column is foreground or background.
[image]

Even the R value says nothing about foreground and background.
As far as I can see, one cannot really say anything about the classification of a pixel unless one sees the bigger picture and realizes that there is a snake in the image.

How then does the paper claim to be able to segment images using regression? How can the homogeneity of a region be detected via regression? [This presentation](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mangas/teaching/320/slides/CSC320L03.pdf) explains the regression part, but does not speak of classification.